Snakemake: Checkpoints and WorkflowError: Missing wildcard values
I'm trying to use the get_txt_files and not_empty_files functions to generate wildcard value lists after specific checkpoints in my workflow.
The first checkpoint is necessary because a rule generates file names that are initially unknown, so I need to capture these wildcard values after the files are created. This is related to a question I asked earlier.
Now, I'm using a second checkpoint because one of the subsequent rules might generate an empty output file. The idea is to update the wildcard values and exclude these empty files from further processing.
However, I'm running into a "Missing wildcard" error. I was able to reproduce this issue with a simplified example, and the code for that example is available here.

Without trying things out yet, my quick guess is the additional expand in your rule all is the issue.  expand(f"{OUTDIR}/"+"{SMP}.doc", SMP=get_txt_files) worked in your older solution here, right? So that is probably not it. But then you added in the new version expand(f"{SNDDIR}/"+"{SMP}_{samples}.txt", file=not_empty_files,samples=samples), yet you didn't include SMP=get_txt_files. I would bet that is then triggering the Missing wildcard values for samples, SMP. This may be easy to test by doing something to ...

 temporarily remove that expand from there. Or without further testing to narrow down the issue just add including what I think you need and see if it fixes it?

What is file=not_empty_files for in expand(f"{SNDDIR}/"+"{SMP}_{samples}.txt", file=not_empty_files,samples=samples)?

In regards to cat {input.s1} {input.s2} > {output.merge}, there is no ouput.merge; it should be cat {input.s1} {input.s2} > {output.merged}.

This sort of works...
There's two Snakefiles I run in succession.
For reasons I cannot understand, I cannot combine them even though I really sort of did. I thought.
I first run the one I purposefully got working only up to making the empty and not empty files. Then I run the one that should do the entire pipeline, I think, and it does the rest because it detects things missing and finishes it. The weird thing is that just running the one that should perform all steps, that is doing the last steps in the current version fine, acts like it expects files and they've been deleted when it is run on its own. Maybe later with fresh eyes, I'll see how to combine it back without getting the error about file disappearing. But if I were working this out myself, this two-step option would be good enough for quite a while and so I'm sharing what I have.
The header for each notebook tells you how to set up a system to run these using MyBinder so you don't mess up your own system trying things. I added clean steps to make iterating convenient.
Go here
and look for SO_pt_2_checkpoints_stuff_working_out.ipynb for your pipeline.
Because of the way the date-dependent sorting works, I added extra steps. To get an idea why check out the other notebook there, 'Data-dependent conditional execution in Snakemake' where I made the documentation example less abstract by giving the rules better names.  However, that example had known inputs from start to finish and not arbitrary named files like here with two wildcards.
